# How to get rid of a #value error in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, error-handling

I was currently trying to figure out this `#Value` error on my Excel spreadsheet on MacOS, but unfortunately I don't know what is causing the error.

Basically I selected the first entry of Ch2 and put a "-" in between and then selected the first entry of Ch1.

I attached an image of the error down below.

[image]

Comment: show us the function in this cell. It's causing the issue.

Comment: the formula I typed in is: =X2-(V2)

Comment: Can you confirm if the values in column X & V are not actually text masquerading as numbers?

Comment: I am not sure. I hope not. How exactly can I check this?

Comment: I selected the "Number" format on all cells, if that's what the question intended to ask :)

Comment: Originally this spreadsheet stems from a CSV file

Comment: Changing the format to "Number" doesn't actually change the underlying value. Most likely you're dealing with text-that-looks-like-a-number. It may need `TRIM`med and `CLEAN`ed.

Comment: try this formula: `=TRIM(CLEAN(X2))-TRIM(CLEAN(V2))` and let us know the outcome.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: I am confused because all of the other data that had to be fitted in the exact same document was formatted properly and the numbers were correctly displayed on the graph

Comment: You may have other characters that `CLEAN` can't remove.

Comment: Can you show us the result if you do : `=NUMBERVALUE(X2)-NUMBERVALUE(V2)` ?

Comment: The problem is solved now, the CSV file wasn't imported correctly